# hide ASP.NET subitems in Visual Studio Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, intellisense

I have created my own controls in ASP.NET Web Forms.

I have created the elements "PADXDropDown", and "PADXDropDownItem".

I was wondering if there is a way to hide PADXDropDownItem from beeing in the big intellisense control list.

[image: Picture of the intellisense list]

but still have it show up when I wanna make the item inside the dropdown

[image: control list inside the dropdown]